# How do I combine pdf files with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pdf

I actually have a pdf file and I want to replace a **word** in it to a **link** of another pdf file

So, in the end, I will have one pdf file containing the previous two pdf files.

I tried a lot of code before, but one of them was panting extra writing on my file and I don't want that

Comment: Please post whatever you have tried. We cannot provide you with a code that solves your problem immediately, you need to show us your attempt.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am the author of the library used in this answer.

1. Use `borb` to concatenate both pdf documents

```py
import typing
from borb.pdf.document.document import Document
from borb.pdf.pdf import PDF

import typing


def main():

    # open doc_001
    doc_001: typing.Optional[Document] = Document()
    with open("output_001.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file_handle:
        doc_001 = PDF.loads(pdf_file_handle)

    # open doc_002
    doc_002: typing.Optional[Document] = Document()
    with open("output_002.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file_handle:
        doc_002 = PDF.loads(pdf_file_handle)

    # merge
    doc_001.append_document(doc_002)

    # write
    with open("output_003.pdf", "wb") as pdf_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(pdf_file_handle, doc_001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

2. Use `borb` to look for the word you would like to replace with a link:

```py
import typing
from borb.pdf.document.document import Document
from borb.pdf.pdf import PDF
from borb.toolkit.text.regular_expression_text_extraction import (
    RegularExpressionTextExtraction,
)


def main():

    # read the Document
    # fmt: off
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    l: RegularExpressionTextExtraction = RegularExpressionTextExtraction("[lL]orem .* [dD]olor")
    with open("output.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle, [l])
    # fmt: on

    # check whether we have read a Document
    assert doc is not None

    # print matching groups
    for i, m in enumerate(l.get_matches_for_page(0)):
        print("%d %s" % (i, m.group(0)))
        for r in m.get_bounding_boxes():
            print(
                "\t%f %f %f %f" % (r.get_x(), r.get_y(), r.get_width(), r.get_height())
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

3. Lastly, you can easily add a link annotation once you have the coordinates of the matching text. The example code I'll post here just places the link annotation in the middle of the page.

```py
        page_width: Decimal = PageSize.A4_PORTRAIT.value[0]
        page_height: Decimal = PageSize.A4_PORTRAIT.value[1]
        s: Decimal = Decimal(100)
        page.append_annotation(
            LinkAnnotation(
                Rectangle(
                    page_width / Decimal(2) - s / Decimal(2),
                    page_height / Decimal(2) - s / Decimal(2),
                    s,
                    s,
                ),
                page=Decimal(0),
                destination_type=DestinationType.FIT,
            )
        )
```

You can find `borb` on [GitHub](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb), or install using `pip install`